# make android build from unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am making a build for android in unity for any project but it always gives the same error

i have tried to reinstall the sdk and reinstall unity but nothing worked

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.0f2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.3.0f2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut down while daemons are in use
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:96)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.RegisteredAaptService.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.workeractions.WorkerActionServiceRegistry$shutdownAllRegisteredServices$1$1.run(WorkerActionServiceRegistry.kt:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
]
stdout[
:checkReleaseClasspath UP-TO-DATE
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:checkReleaseManifest
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:prepareLintJar
:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
10 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 2 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at :0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: You should see if the `-stacktrace` output to the console gives hints higher up. This is almost certainly a failure that is a symptom of a real failure earlier on. Thsi would help decide which of the previous question that show related errors might be related. (And, yes, if you search for that IllegalStateException you get a lot of previous Q&A.)

Comment: @jdv i don't know what is the -stacktrace, would you tell me where to find it? or how to use it please?

Comment: Run the same Gradle build from the Terminal, passing it `--stacktrace`. The Gradle wrapper ("gradlew") should be setup for you. It'll be something like `gradlew.bat --stacktrace :MyModule:MyTask`. The Build or Run Panels will tell you what task it was working on when it failed, if you want to just run a more focused test against that task dependency. I encourage you to look for this IllegalStateException with the same details found in many other Q&A here.